# Sample of using limitRetries in Haskell from Control.Retries

Tags: haskell, exception

The Retry package looks neat:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/retry-0.7/candidate/docs/Control-Retry.html

I have a typical

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  stuff
```

I'd like to retry it 5 times with exponential backoff.

I understand there's a policy for:

```
exponentialBackoff
limitRetries
```

And a policy transformer for:

```
limitRetriesByDelay
```

I also understand

> The default under def implements a constant 50ms delay, up to 5 times

First: How can I wrap my `main` in this (or my `stuff` function) in order to retry 5 times with exponential backoff?

Second: is this a good package for dealing with failure, or are other exception-handling techniques better or more idiomatic?

Comment: To make this work, you probably just need `main = recoverAll (exponentialBackoff 50 <> limitRetries 5) (const stuff)`.

Comment: Hmm, I think that worked.  I couldn't import Data.Monoid (<>) it seems, had to use import Data.Monoid (mappend).

Comment: You probably forgot the extra set of parens you need around operators you import: `import Data.Monoid ((<>))`. :)

Comment: I'm using `die "error happened"` inside my stuff function.  Any chance you have recommendations for something better: is it a better idea maybe if `stuff -> IO Bool` rather than file system die commands?  It seems to work, but seems inelegant.

Comment: Depends what you are doing. Personally, I don't see any reason to avoid `error` if you are describing an exception that should fail pretty hard. I generally choose between `Control.Monad.Except`, `Control.Exception` (`IO` related),  and `error`.

Comment: @Alec, I disagree firmly about `error`, which I believe should only be used for internal errors (cases that should be impossible). 1. It can be difficult to turn a non-recoverable error expressed using `error` into a recoverable one if your needs change--the program may have to be restructured. 2. Errors are likely to be thrown late (as a result of laziness), which makes debugging hard and can cause a program to behave badly when an old error thunk gets forced in the middle of some sensitive I/O action.

Comment: @dfeuer, do you have recommended reading on how to do it properly?

Comment: @Alec, if you make your comment an answer, I'll accept.